# __cmp__ method is this not working as expected in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.x, cmp

```
class x:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __cmp__(self,other):
        print("cmp method called with self="+str(self)+",other="+str(other))
        return self.name==other.name
       # return False


instance1=x("hello")
instance2=x("there")

print(instance1==instance2)
print(instance1.name==instance2.name)
```

The output here is:

```
cmp method called with self=hello,other=there
True
False
```

Which is not what I expected: I'm trying to say 'two instances are equal if the name fields are equal'.

If I simply `return False` from the `__cmp__` function, this reports as `True` as well!!
If I return `-1`, then I get `False` - but since I'm trying to compare strings, this doesn't feel right.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__cmp__(x,y)` should return a negative number (e.g. -1) if `x < y`, a positive number (e.g. 1) if `x > y` and 0 if `x == y`. You should never return a boolean with it.

What you're overloading is `__eq__(x, y)`.

Comment: Thankyou - you get the tickmark (even though other people provided similar information), as this is the clearest explanation!

Comment: As others commented, __cmp__() is obsolete. Define __lt__(), __eq__(), and __gt__() instead. As per http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Answer (score 5):

the `__cmp__` method should return -1, 0 or 1, when self < other, self == other, self > other respectvelly.

You can do

```
return cmp(self.name, other.name)
```

in your code for a proper result

Comment: Thanks ! Turns out I meant '__eq__' !

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing `__cmp__` with `__eq__`.

[From the documentation of `__cmp__`:](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

> Should return a negative integer if self < other, zero if self == other, a positive integer if self > other.

`__eq__` returns a boolean which determines if two objects are equal, `__cmp__` returns an integer which determines if the two objects are greater or less than each other, and so is called unless you have specific `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__le__`, `__ge__`, `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods.

In your case you do want a `__cmp__` method rather than `__eq__` as it will save you implementing the other 5 methods for the other comparisons.

You could use the [`cmp()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) and put the following in your `__cmp__` method:

```
return cmp(self.name,other.name)
```

Note, [as highlighted by Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146225/cmp-method-is-this-not-working-as-expected-in-python-2-x/2146242#2146242)  is this [isn't the preferred method in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons), but in Python 2.x `__cmp__` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

`__cmp__()` is obsolescent. Define `__lt__()`, `__eq__()`, and `__gt__()` instead.

Even so, you're doing it wrong. You're supposed to return an integer.

Comment: "obsolescent"?? Where did you pick this from? The others exist, but in most cases it makes more sense to use __cmp__,  in this case, for example, it would  take 3 methods instead of just one. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: @jsbueno: Third bullet point: http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: URL has moved to http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the documentation for [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__), youre supposed to return an integer:

> Should return a negative integer if
>   self < other, zero if self == other, a
>   positive integer if self > other.